# Matching content within a string with one regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking for a way to RegEx match for a string (double quote followed by one or more letter, digit, or space followed by another double quote).  For example, if the input was `var s = "\"this is a string\""`, I would like to create a RegEx to match this string and produce a result of [""this is a string""].

Thank you!

Comment: means instead of var s = "this is a string" this you want display ["this is a string"] like this ?

Comment: Look for a regex escaping library, and then use the `RegExp` constructor

Comment: i'm not looking to pass a variable to a RegEx, just a pattern to match a double quote followed by one or more characters(letters, digits, spaces) followed by another double quote

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`RegExp` constructor function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Creating_a_Regular_Expression).

```
var s = "this is a string";
var re = new RegExp(s);
```

Note that you may need to [quote the input string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2593661/139010).

Comment: It should be expanded beyond a note

Comment: Yup, I'm working on it...

Comment: Voted. That question always takes me a while to find.

Comment: you should replace the mataChars like `var metaChars = /([[\]\*{}\^\$\\.|?+-])/g; var re = new RegExp(s.replace(metaChars, '\\$1'));`

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you need.

```
s =~ /"[^"]*"/
```

The regex matches a double quote, followed by some number of non-quotes, followed by a quote. You'll run into problems if your string has a quote in it, like this:

```
var s = "\"I love you,\" she said"
```

Then you'll need something a bit more complicated like this:

```
s =~ /"([^"]|\\")*"/
```

Comment: I don't think bitwise-negating a regex is a good idea. Did you mistake a language?

Answer (score 0):

I just needed a pattern to match a double quote followed by one or more characters(letters, digits, spaces) followed by another double quote so this did it for me:

`/"[^"]*"/`